# Push notification capabilities

Tags: ios, push-notification

1) If I want to send simultaneously e.g. 10 thousand push notifications, do I have this capability?

2) Can push notifications interact with other apps? To explain this: If I want something to be done when a push notification is sent to another app, does Apple act as a middle man, or the other developer has to give me the tokens of his clients in order to send them the notifications directly?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) If you have 10,000 devices to send the push to then that should be possible. If you sent 10,000 to the same device the Apple servers would detect that and block it most probably.

2) Your question is not clear. A push is a message sent from a server to an app. The server that is sending the push needs to be signed with the push certificate of whatever app it is sending the push to, also the app needs to send its push token to the server before the server can send the push. 
A server is not an iOS app so to say "when a push notification is sent to another app" does not make sense. If you are talking about a server sending a push to more than one app, then provided the server is signed with the relevant certificates and has the device tokens it can do whatever it wants.

Comment: It's okay, I understood what I initially wanted. I know it wasn't so clear, but the answer was spot on.